# Bar item button not displayed at runtime but visible at design time in a modal view

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, interface-builder, xcode8

I have being trying different things and looking around for a while without finding an answer to my problem. Maybe I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

The sample application consists of:

- A first view controller that displays a second view controller using a segue. This works fine.
- A second view controller, in which I have simulated the display of a third view programmatically, which contains a bar item button (named "Done") that I would like to display.

The bar item button in the third view controller is not displayed at runtime but is displayed in IntefaceBuidler at design time.

This third view controller needs to be displayed modal.

What I'm doing wrong to display this bar item button?

[A sample project illustrating the problem is available here.](https://bitbucket.org/JackG/display-view-controller-with-done-button-programmatically)

Below a screen capture of the bar item button at design time:

[image]

Below a screen capture of the bar item button not showing at design time:

[image]

PS:
Please disregard the "Unknown class ThirdViewControlller in Interface Builder file.", since the ThirdViewController is displayed fine at runtime. Also, the "Done" button in the middle of the view works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `SecondViewController` you need to push the third onto the navigation controller stack like so:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(thirdViewController, animated: true)
```

You are currently presenting it as a modal. Also, you've unnecessarily added a second `UINavigationController` to your storyboard (for the third view controller)

If you want to present a modal, then you'd need to embed the controller in a navigation controller:

```
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: thirdViewController)
self.present(navController, animated: false)
```

If you prefer to keep this within the storyboard, then you need to provide a identifier for the `UINavigationController` and insatiate that in your function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the bar item button is needed in a modal view. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Then you need to embed your view controller in a `UINavigationController`. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks to your feedback I got it working. The sample application has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

The above button is a navigation bar item that will only be displayed on the navigation bar . For achieving your desired result , you first have to embed the navigation controller at least in your second viewcontroller and then you should do a push segue rather than modal . Navigation controller can be added by

- whith your second viewcontroller selected go to **Editor\Embed In\Navigation Controller**
- for pushing the viewcontroller programatically onto user navigation controller's stack use

`self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but your solution doesn't comply with the requirement, i.e. displaying a modal view controller.